# NPM: Invalid package name "untitled folder": name can only contain URL-friendly characters

Tags: npm

NPM is reporting this error when I try to install or uninstall within my packages:

```
Invalid package name "untitled folder": name can only contain URL-friendly characters
```

Using VS Code to search my files, I find that NPM's auto-generated package-lock.json files all contain the string "untitled folder" as a key

What should I do at this point? I've seen some people online just delete package-lock.json and redo the npm install ... seems like there should be a better way to avoid this issue?

Comment: By the way, the delete package-lock.json and redo npm install works, and the newly generated package-lock.json no longer contains "untitled folder". I did find an untitled folder in the node_modules of one dependency ... I deleted it and did npm cache clear but that didn't resolve issue

Comment: I just deleted the package-lock.json files and npm installed on my packages. Short of it is, I think that the untitled folder in a dependency messed with NPM. I'm not sure how that folder was introduced ... perhaps flying fingers though